# React native keyboard should push only textinput not whole screen

Tags: react-native, native, rect

I have a video player and at bottom i have TextInput, when i click on TextInput, keyboard pushing up whole page. I just want keyboard to push up only TextInput not whole page.

I have tried:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

But nothing helped me. I even tried layout resize.